# How can I calculate the frecuency of this circuit?

Tags: 555, astable

If RA=RC= 15Kohms, RB=44Kohms and C = 8.2uf, Which will ve the frecuency?

[image]

It's like a astable circuit with 555, but the resistence RC conected to Discharge is confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done the math yet?

Comment: Ignacio, I tried, but it's wrong. I'm not considerating the RC resistor, and I don't found an astable circuit with 3 resistors, and I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: You calculate the currents and voltages, and find out when they hit the threshold.

Comment: Find the Thevenin equivalent with Rc included and calculate the when the exponential discharge hits 1/3 Vcc. Hint: If Rc is too high it will never get there.

Answer (score 2):

In the circuit you've shown there will be no frequency;  there'll only be a single output pulse, as shown below.

Here's how it works:

When the circuit powers up, C1 will start out discharged, which will pull TRIG  low, force OUT high, and make DIS go open collector.

C1 will then start charging toward Vcc through R1 and R2, and when THRS detects that the voltage across C1  has risen to 2/3 Vcc, OUT will go low and DIS will be connected to ground through a low impedance.

C1 will now start discharging through R2 and R3, and when it gets to 1/3 Vcc the plan is that TRIG will detect that voltage then force OUT high, starting the cycle anew.

The problem with this circuit is that when DIS is ON and discharging C1,  R1 and R3 form a voltage divider which keeps C1 from ever  falling below Vcc/2, the consequence being that TRIG will never see Vcc/3 and, after the first pulse, OUT will remain low forever.

I've shown the 1/3 and 2/3 Vcc points on the green trace, showing how 1/3 Vcc can never be reached after the initial pulse.

Left click the image for full-screen.

[image]